# TFS agent have no permissions in a folder

Tags: powershell, tfs, build, permissions, build-agent

I have a PowerShell script which needs to access a folder and to make stuff inside it (like deleting or renaming a subfolder). I think it crashes because my on-premises TFS agent is denied to access this folder in this remote machine. The error message is:

> 2017-10-12T12:49:06.6816226Z ##[error]Remove-Item : Cannot remove item
>   \[path_to_the_folder_I_want_my_script_to_access]\old.1: Access to the
>   path
>
> 2017-10-12T12:49:06.6835446Z ##[error]is denied.

I googled the problem and found a probable solution: giving the read/write permissions to the folder accessed by the script to the Build Service Account of my TFS (Svc_tfsbuild account). But it doesn't work.

So if someone has another solution, it would be awesome. :D

Thank you so much in advance.

Have a great day!

---

Comment: Try running PowerShell as an administrator also it probably would be helpful to post your code. We may notice something you don't see.

Comment: In fact, the code did work with another agent, a TFS test agent, but not with the one I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the permission issue, make sure you have correctly set the permission to let the Build Agent service account to access the folder.

You said that "`the code did work with another agent, a TFS test agent`", So you can compare the Build Agent service account with the test agent service account to correct the permission settings.

Another workaround is running the Remove-Item command **with the specific credential** which has the sufficient permission to remove the folder/files. If the account works locally ,then it will also work during the building process. I tested and worked at my side.

You can use below sample script to do that:

```
Param(
  [string]$computerName = "vtinmo502vm",
  [string]$path ="C:\Software\test.txt"
)
$Username = "domain\user"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "EnterPasswordHere" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$password) 
Invoke-Command -computername $computerName {Remove-Item -path $args[0] -Recurse} -cred $cred  -ArgumentList $path
```